# concat string IE8 SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, string-concatenation

I have this simple Javascript for string concatenation:

```
function stampaLista(store) {

lista = "<table ><tr>" +
         "<td class='titoloLista' style='width:80px'>Data Ins.</td>" +
         "<td class='titoloLista' style='width:130px'>Data/Ora Attività</td>" +
         "<td class='titoloLista' style='width:100px'>Tipologia</td>" +
         "<td class='titoloLista' style='width:30px'>Stato</td>" +
         "<td class='titoloLista' style='width:150px'>Utente ins.</td>" +
         "<td class='titoloLista' style='width:150px'>Utente designato</td>" +
         "<td class='titoloLista' style='width:250px'>Anagrafica</td>" +
         "<td class='titoloLista' style='width:30px'>Vai</td>" +
         "</tr>";


for (i=0; i<store.length; i++) { 

    lista += "<tr >" +
        "<td class='rigaLista'>" + store[i].dataIns + "</td>" +
        "<td class='rigaLista'>" + store[i].dataAtt + " " + store[i].oraAtt + "</td>" +
        "<td class='rigaLista'>" + store[i].idTipoAttivita + "</td>" +
        "<td class='rigaLista'>" + store[i].stato + "</td>" +
        "<td class='rigaLista'>" + store[i].utenteIns + "</td>" +
        "<td class='rigaLista'>" + store[i].utenteAtt + "</td>" +
        "<td class='rigaLista'>" + store[i].anagrafica + "</td>" +
        "<td class='rigaLista'>" + "<div class='go' ><a id='" + store[i].id + "' href='#' class='go' return;><img alt='" + store[i].id + "' src='images/go.gif'  /></a>" + "</div></td>" +
        "</tr>";            

};

lista += "</table>";                
lista += "<div class='clearfloat'>&nbsp;</div>";

return lista;

}
```

but with IE8 I had error, on both population of "lista":

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method

The problem is solved with IE9 but i need to work also with IE8 due to customer requirements.

Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot

Fabrizio

Comment: Why not just separate out the HTML from the javascript? Without seeing more of the code its hard to give a solution.

Comment: I have to create a table dinamically from an ajax call

Comment: Couldn't you just have the table structure in HTML and append the data from the ajax call to the table? It will improve the accessibility of the application.

Comment: Yes, I can but i need the "for" cicle with the second part of the concat that give the same problem

Comment: Because there is HTML mixed with javascript Make sure there is no html element ids has the same id as some variable in the javascript function.

Comment: @luke2012, you're rigth !!! lista is my string var but it's also an html element id. Changing javascript var name the problem is solved !! thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is HTML mixed with Javascript Make sure there is no HTML element `id` with the same `id` as a variable in the Javascript function.